# Linux で疎通確認のためポートに応答するサーバーをたてるコマンド

Tags: linux, network, tcp, command-line

AWS EC2 上でサーバープログラムをたてる前の何もない状態で
セキュリティグループの設定があってるかネットワークの疎通確認がしたいです

クライアント側は telnet なり curl なりを使えばいいと思うのですが
サーバー側でポート番号を指定して bind して listen して
echo なり簡易的な応答をしてくれるようなコマンドやプログラムはないでしょうか

TCP のコネクションハンドシェイクが確認できればいいので
receive や response すらなくてよくて 
bind と listen だけして
接続が来たら標準出力になんかはいてくれればいいんですが

自分でかくしかないでしょうか

Answer (score 9, accepted):

簡易 TCP サーバーとして使える nc コマンドで待ち受けておくのはいかがでしょうか。

```sh
nc -l 〈ポート番号〉
```

改造例: [nc コマンドで簡易HTTPサーバ](http://blog.livedoor.jp/sonots/archives/34703829.html)

あるいは Python のワンライナーで HTTP サーバーを立ててしまうのも OK そうです。

```sh
# Python 3
python -m http.server 〈ポート番号〉
```

他言語でもワンライナーでサーバーを立てられる場合があります: [ワンライナーWebサーバを集めてみた](https://qiita.com/sudahiroshi/items/e74d61d939f18779970d)

Answer (score 6):

nekketsuuuさんが提案されているように`nc -l`がベストだと思います。その上で参考までに…

歴史的には[`inetd`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd)がその機能を提供しています。`inetd.conf`にポート番号に対して応答を行う実行ファイル名を記述すれば、`inetd`が通信処理を引き受けます。更に受信したデータをオウム返しする`echo`プロトコル程度であれば`inetd`が組み込み提供してくれる場合もあります。

詳しくはご利用のディストリビューションで提供される`inetd`を確認ください。

Comment: 歴史的には inetd が使われていましたが、現在では [xinetd](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinetd) に置き換えられている場合がほとんどかと思います。

Comment: @cubick さらに [`systemd`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) に置き換えられていたりして本質的でなくなるため、あえて `inetd` を紹介しました。